# Get inline message info from inline_message_id and query_id in Pyrogram

Tags: telegram, inline, pyrogram

I am trying to get information about an inline message sent by my bot in order to edit it. The message has an inline keyboard attached and, on the pression of a button, the message should be edited. The edit should be based on the information contained in the message and its keyboard.

**Problem**: when a user presses a button from that inline keyboard, my bot only receives information about that `callback_query`, not about the whole keyboard nor the text written in the message. Now, since my editing should use that information, I am trying to retrieve them using some method call like `get_messages`, but this does not seem to work since inline messages don't have a `Chat` object and their `inline_message_id` is not even a number.

So I went looking at the docs, both from Pyrogram and Telegram itself, and I found out that there is a raw method `GetMessages` which takes as input a list of `InputMessage`, and one constructor for `InputMessage` is `InputMessageID`, which seems correct for my case since it does not require a `chat_id`. So i tried building an `InputMessageID` using the `inline_message_id` from the `RawUpdate` (because the non-raw update `CallbackQuery` had different types (str instead of int) for some reason). The problem here is that `GetMessages` returns a `MessageEmpty` object.

Here is the code:

```
async def edit_inline_message(client: Client, update: UpdateInlineBotCallbackQuery, users, chats):
    # according to https://core.telegram.org/constructor/inputBotInlineMessageID
    # inputBotInlineMessageID.id has this format
    user_id, message_id = update.msg_id.id >> 32, update.msg_id.id & 0xFFFFFFFF
    print(
        await client.send(
            GetMessages(
                id = [InputMessageID(id = message_id)]
            )
        )
    )
```

and the result:

```
{
    "_": "types.messages.Messages",
    "messages": [
        {
            "_": "types.MessageEmpty",
            "id": 1473846
        }
    ],
    "chats": [],
    "users": []
}
```

I also tried using `InputMessageCallbackQuery` instead of `InputMessageID` but the result is even worse:

```
{
    "_": "types.messages.Messages",
    "messages": [],
    "chats": [],
    "users": []
}
```

Comment: Have you got solution for this problem yet?

Comment: callback_query return `chat_instance` and `inline_query_message_id` so we should get inline message info here

Comment: @TinHuynh I don't see inline_query_message_id tho chat_instance is there but chat_instance is not inline_query_message_id is there anyone who have solution for this?